# Win Loss Simulation

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to create a simulation for the wins an nfl team for the season.  I created a code that will create a vector length of 16 with "win" or "loss" as the elements based the the criteria I created.

I am struggling on getting R to count the number of wins in the vector and setting it up to simulate the test multiple times

Here is the code I used to create the vector

```
schedule <- c(0.707, 0.594, 0.455, 0.487, 0.505, 0.327, 0.643, 0.525, 0.513,0.545, 0.500, 0.293, 0.545,  0.487, 0.465, 0.500)

random <- runif(16)

trial <- ifelse(random < schedule, "win","loss")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this `runs` number of times (change the value from 10 to whatever you need) and just keep track of the number of wins, this is one way:

```r
set.seed(1)

schedule <- c(0.707, 0.594, 0.455, 0.487, 0.505, 0.327, 0.643, 0.525, 0.513,0.545, 0.500, 0.293, 0.545, 0.487, 0.465, 0.500)

runs = 10

results = rep(NA, runs)

for (trial_run in 1:runs) {
  random <- runif(16)
  #trial <- ifelse(random < schedule, "win","loss")
  results[trial_run] <- sum(random < schedule)
}
results
#>  [1]  8  7  7  9  8  9  5 11  6 11
```

Created on 2020-10-20 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really close to what you want. Maybe you should try `replicate` + `table` like below

```
runs <- 5
trial <- replicate(runs,table(ifelse(runif(16) < schedule, "win","loss")),simplify = FALSE)
```

which gives result like

```
> trial
[[1]]

loss  win
   6   10

[[2]]

loss  win
  12    4

[[3]]

loss  win 
   6   10

[[4]]

loss  win
   5   11

[[5]]

loss  win
   6   10
```